# Generating a consistent dynamic color palette in ggplot within a loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set called d1 similar to:

```
location, depth.from, depth.to, val, type
```

I have a loop that creates a fairly complex plot for each unique location (it's glueing together many things using `grid.arrange`, which is why I can't use `facet_wrap` on the location to keep the legend/color consistent of one part of the plot).

Say there are 4 categories for "type", the problem when one location has a different number of "types" than the other, the colors assigned are not consistent between each plot.  I can manually force them to be the same, but I am trying to generalize this function.  Google has failed me.

For the following block, d1 is a subset of the data based on the location type, e.g.

```
d1 <- subset(myData, location == location.list[i])
```

Looking at the plot, which is within the loop:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = d1, aes (y=val, x=depth.from))+
layer(geom = "point", size = 2) + 
geom_rect(data=d1, aes(xmin=Depth.to, xmax=Depth.from, ymin=0, ymax=100, fill = type), linetype =0, alpha=0.3)+
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

the geom_rect command is going through the data and based on the depth from and depth to, creating a overlay based on fill type.  I can use `scale_fill_manual("Lith", c("Val1" = "DodgerBlue4"...)` etc to manually set it, but that defeats the purposes. If I have:types like where I want something like:

```
Bird_one = blue
Bird_two = red
Bird_three = green
```

I want `bird_three` to be green, even if `bird_two` doesn't exist, without having to explicitly set it using `scale_fill_manual`.   Is there a way to set a global list of names for the color palette?  Perhaps by providing the array from something like:

```
myData <- read.csv("mydata.csv" 
typeList <- unique(myData$type)
```

Comment: Some really good answers here!  I appreciate the help.  I've gone with the scale_fill_brewer(limits = levels(dat$type), palette = "Set1") solution which seems to be working for everything that I'm throwing at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty late, but there actually is a trivial solution by setting `scale_fill_discrete(drop=F)`

```
plots <- lapply(dfs, function(df) {
  ggplot(df, 
    aes(
      x=location, fill=type, 
      y=(depth.from + depth.to) / 2, 
      ymin=depth.from, ymax=depth.to
  ) ) +
  geom_crossbar() + scale_fill_discrete(drop=F)
})
library(gridExtra)
do.call(grid.arrange, plots)
```

[image]

And here is dummy data I used:

```
set.seed(12)
items <- 2
dfs <- 
  replicate(2, simplify=F,
    data.frame(
      location=sample(letters, items), 
      depth.from=runif(items, -10, -5),
      depth.to=runif(items, 5, 10),
      val=runif(items),
      type=factor(
        sample(c("Bird_one", "Bird_two", "Bird_three"), items),
        levels=c("Bird_one", "Bird_two", "Bird_three")
  ) ) )
```

Comment: @hadley, I'm not sure what you mean by "set the limits to the scale" in the previous answer, but wouldn't this be the correct way to do it?

Comment: that's neat - what I would like is something similar, but doesn't maintain the absent levels in the legend... I'll do some investigating

Answer (score 6):

It is not important whether or not they are in a loop, you just need to associate each level with a colour. In your case:

```
colourList <- c(bird_one = "red", bird_two = "blue", bird_three = "green")
```

In a simple example:

```
#Make some data
dat <- data.frame(location = rep(1:4, c(3,2,2,3)), val = rnorm(10), 
  depth.from = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE), depth.to = sample(6:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
  type = factor(LETTERS[c(1:3, 1,3,1,3,1:3)]))

#Associate levels with colours
colourList <- c(A = "red", B = "blue", C = "green")

p <- list()
for(i in 1:4) {
  d <- dat[dat$location == i,]
  p[[i]] <- ggplot(data = d, aes (y=val, x=depth.from))+
    layer(geom = "point", size = 2) + 
    geom_rect(aes(xmin=depth.to, xmax=depth.from, ymin=0, ymax=100, fill = type), linetype =0, alpha=0.3) +
    #This is where the assignment works
    scale_fill_manual(values=colourList)
}
grid.arrange(p[[1]], p[[2]])
```

You can see that level `C` is green in both plots.

In response to @BrodieG, here is a way to set the colours semi-automatically. It is creating the named vector using the levels of `type` and colour values from the RColorBrewer package. This could be developed pretty easily to include in a function:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
colourList <- setNames(brewer.pal(length(levels(dat$type)), "Set1"), levels(dat$type))
```

As @hadley points out, in this instance it's even more straightforward to set the limits of the scale, although in my typical use I find it more useful to setup an object like `colourList` which can be used across multiple plots by just setting `values`. Setting `limits` also maintains the levels for the legend, which may or may not be what is wanted:

```
scale_fill_brewer(limits = levels(dat$type), palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

As @hadley points out, in this instance it's even more straightforward to set the limits of the scale, although in my typical use I find it more useful to setup an object like `colourList` which can be used across multiple plots by just setting `values`. Setting `limits` also maintains the levels for the legend, which may or may not be what is wanted:

```
scale_fill_brewer(limits = levels(dat$type), palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

Comment: But is there a way to do this without specifying the color scale manually, even if only once.  I think this is what the OP is trying to do.  For example, I was hoping that by using a factor with the same levels for both plots, that the color mapping would be done on the levels, not on the unique values in the factor.  Unfortunately it is the latter.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's as good as it gets without actually modifying `ggplot`.  Ideally there would be a direct way of doing this.  Since `ggplot` derives so much of it's behavior from levels (series ordering, etc.), I would have thought it would do this (though to be fair, missing elements in factors don't show up as empty spots on a categorical bar plot either).

Comment: @alexwhan, fyi, I stumbled onto the answer (see above).